# Ignoring vertex labels, how many distinct trees are there with 5 vertices?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

[image]***Question:***

Ignoring vertex labels, how many distinct trees are there with 5 vertices? Draw each such tree, and justify your conclusion that there are no more. (You may assume without proof that any tree on n vertices has exactly n-1 edges.)

***Where I am at so far***

I understand that a tree is a graph which is connected (which means from any vertex you can walk to any other vertex) and acyclic (which means the graph contains no cycles).

The only distinct trees on 5 vertices I can think of is *a star with 5 vertices* and a *path of length 4*, denoted $P_4$. Are there any other distinct graphs? Also how would I prove that there are no more?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Dynkin diagram $D_5$, a.k.a $E_5$?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Nope, I've never heard of it.

Comment: Well then, happy first meeting.

Comment: Would it be correct to assume that you don't know what a tree centre / bicentre is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your tree step by step:

1- A 5-vertex tree must have a vertex: 0

2- This vertex must have a neighbour (a tree is connected): 0-0 (no other option)

3- At least one of these vertices must have another neighbour: 0-0-0 (again no other options).

4- Adding a fourth vertex you have two options (which are?).

5- Then in both cases you have again exactly two options to add a fifth vertex. This yields $4$ trees, but two of them are actually identical.

In the end you have the two trees that you found, plus the Dynkin diagram $D_5$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: @CubbyKushi You're very welcome.

Comment: Ignoring vertex labels, there are three trees with 5 vertices. How do we justify out conclusion that there are no more? Or does the solution you gave where you detailed how to from the 3 tree already prove that there are no more?

Comment: @CubbyKushi It does prove that, yes.